# How to match the pattern between a specified characters?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a fixed message delimited by "|"... tag=value is the pair between the delimiter;

> `(8=FIX.4.2|9=0360|35=8|49=BLPFT|56=ESP|34=8415|52=20110201-15:59:59|50=MBA|143=LN|115=MSET|57=2457172|30=CHIX|60=20110201-15:59:59.121|150=1|31=56.3100|151=71785|32=137|6=56.4058|37=9D9ZIhgu4BGU9sBtfHcYeQA|38=97370|39=1|40=1|11=20110201-05529|12=0.0012|13=2|14=25585|15=EUR|76=CHIXCCP|17=272674|47=A|167=CS|18=1|48=FR0000131104|20=0|21=1|22=4|113=N|54=1|55=BNP|207=FP|29=1|59=0|10=205|)`

How to extract a data between "11=" and a first occurrence of "|" after a match?

For example i want a data

> `20110201-05529`

which is between "|11=" and "|"

Can you please tell me the regular expression?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Have you read the regex documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach will depend on how much you know about the data you are trying to match. If you know it will be comprised of numbers and dashes only:

```
m/11=([0-9\-]+)/
```

Conversely, if the data could contain any kind of characters, use:

```
m/11=([^|]+)/
```

Which matches anything that *isn't* a pipe character. This is probably the most reliable expression.

In both cases, the data you want is captured into the `$1` special variable.

If you don't always want to match the value for the key 11, you can use variables in the pattern, so:

```
my $key = 42; # or any number
if ($text =~ m/$key=([^|]+)/) {
    print "I found $1"; # prints "I found 20110201-05529"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, there is more than 1 way to solve the problem. Therefore, there is no such thing as "the regular expression".
But you will definitely want to perldoc split.

Comment: This isn't a very helpful answer.

Comment: It wasn't great, but splitting on | and then = would have effected some kind of workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will match everything else than = then everything else than |

```
[^=]+=([^|])+
```